# Zend Debugger - Cannot send message

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio, zend-debugger, zend-server-ce

I have a few problems with setting up the Zend Debugger. I have installed the Zend Server CE.
I am using Zend Studio as my development environment.

In Zend Studio under Debug Configurations, i can test the Debugger. Everything works fine.
But when i try to debug my project, the browser pops up and shows the right page but the debug session is terminated directly. I set a breakpoint in my IndexController but the debug session is terminated directly.

Under my Zend Server Logs tab, the Server Error Log says "[Zend Debugger] Cannot send message".

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is the server remote or local? If it is remote are you sure the Zend Debugger port is allowed across the network? You may need to create an SSH tunnel as described here http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=109.

Comment: Its still the same. The Debug Session is terminated directly

Comment: Could it be a port problem? If so, how can i test from my windows 7 pc if the port of my ubuntu server with zend server installed is opened?